# Sharepoint Photo Gallary Webpart

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, web-parts

I want to craete a simple Photo Gallery web part in which I can fetch images stored in a picture library on my site and I want to do it with JQUERY.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example using [Lytebox](http://www.dolem.com/lytebox/) (a self contained javascript photo display with no external dependencies) with SharePoint

- [Using Lytebox with SharePoint](http://padavis.wordpress.com/2008/10/05/web-20-popup-using-lytebox-with-sharepoint/)

And Randy Drisgill has created a codeplex project based on the same

- [Codeplex - Lytebox for
  SharePoint](http://lyteboxsp.codeplex.com/)

You mention "want to do it with jQuery" - I wonder if that is a requirement or a wish? Contrary to popular belief there are actually other ways of doing things ;)

If it absolutely necessary to use jQuery then the above can serve as inspiration.